# how to use spring data jpa or queryDsl to query only one field in the entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I don't want to use @Query annotation and other string sql,for example:`@Query("select u.moduleName from UserBehaviorLog u group by u.moduleName order by u.createdDate desc ")`.Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can definitely do it. Have a look here [introduction to Spring data JPA queries](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-introduction-to-query-methods/)

It works like this, consider a Entity class as (I am omitting annotations purposely)

```
Class Employee{
      Integer id;
      String name;
}
```

consider the CRUD repository as

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends Repository<Employee, Integer> {
      Employee findById(Integer id); // this method returns Employee object whose id we provide.
}
```

if you want to search employee based on name, you just need to insert a method in repository by name.

```
findByName(String name);
```

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant,I only want to query one filed of entity,such as  name.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You have to use the @Query annotation.